# amslatex plus endnotes

Tags: endnotes, amsbook

I have a document that uses `\usepackage{endnotes}`. When the document class is `book` it works fine but when the document class is `amsbook`, I exceed TeX capacity with `stack_size`, `save_size` and `param_size` set as large is `pdftex` will allow.

1) Any suggestions as to why `amsbook` doesn't like `endnotes`?

2) Is there an `endnotes` package that does get along with `amsbook`?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: here at ams we've successfully published at least one book that used `endnotes` along with a document class based on `amsbook`.  if you provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) i will try to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the definition of `\enoteheading` in `endnotes.sty`; call the package in this way:

```
\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand\enoteheading{\chapter*{\notesname}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
```

If you want endnotes at the end of every chapter, use `\section*` instead of `\chapter*`